# Wiper motor internal park switching

Tags: motor, relay, automotive

I have revised this posting on the off-chance that someone else in the future is interested in what I discovered.

TL;DR: I *plannned* to use an AX159060 wiper motor in an automotive project, but found that the "park" switch appears to be normally open, not the typical normally closed. The (AE)159300 motor is nearly identical to the AX159060 motor, but the park is of the typical normally closed style.

Background: I originally planned to use an AX159060 wiper motor in my project to modernize the windshield wipers on a 1970s Datsun. It appeared to be a convenient form factor, and was relatively common.

However, in my testing, I found that the parking feature worked unusually and decided that a different motor would suit my needs better. The motor I decided to replace it with was an (AE)159300 whose internal switching is arranged better for my application. In my searching, I found a schematic for both the AX159060 and (AE)159300 motors which I have attached below for anyone interested.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1Ww5-pmiokc

AX159060 used in 2008-2015 Cadillac CTS and 2007-2010 GM trucks. My motor followed the "W/O DENSO" path and never connected Pin 3 and Pin 5 under any circumstance.
Schematic: https://www.silveradosierra.com/electrical/2010-1500-windshield-wiper-motor-wiring-t239857.html

[image]

(AE)159300 used in 2006-2018 Toyota RAV4, 2008-2014 Subaru Impreza, and *MANY* more. Schematic Page 186: https://frankensteinmotorworks.com/2GRFE/diagrams/Toyota%20RAV4%20Electrical%20Wiring%20Diagrams%20%28EWD%29.pdf

[image]

These two wiper motors appear to share a common manufacturer, however I have no proof of this. My hunch is that Toyota makes these motors and then sells them to other companies with unique part numbers according to the application.

I find the Toyota wiper motor to be a convenient form factor, and seems like an ideal choice for design projects or to upgrade from a NLA part.

Comment: What is a "cutsheet?"

Comment: Technical data sheet or other product documentation.

Answer (score 2):

A SPST switch may be used when the motor is controlled by an Electronic Control Unit (ECU) with two relays - one for Hi/Low and the other for Run/Brake. The SPST switch is read by the controlling Microprocessor. It is possible for the park position to be adjusted - if the Park switch actuates slightly earlier in the sweep, then the micro-controller can delay the brake actuation for a certain time (10s-100s of ms) to optimize the parking position. This time can be programmed for each individual car to take account of mechanical variation and installation tolerances.

Answer (score 1):

A double pole, 3 position, rotary switch is to be used to control the 2-speed, self-parking wiper motor.

[image]

Comment: @jsotola, Thank you very much for pointing it out. The error has been rectified. I regret the oversight.

Comment: I have modified your drawing to explain how the internal wiring and switching appears to be wired. What you attached seems to be standard, and is how I expected this motor to be wired as well.

Comment: Just an 'NO' contact, actuated only in the parked position, would serve no purpose.

Comment: I agree, it seems almost worthless. But I have checked and rechecked the motor, and that is how it was built. I am stuck because it seems to be a perfect motor for my application besides this strange park switch. I am hoping there is some way I can make it work regardless, which is why I asked. Thank you for looking into it.

Comment: Anytime, Chris!

Comment: I found a schematic for my original wiper motor, and have attached a screenshot above. I have since decided to switch to a different motor with a more typical park switch similar to the one you have described above. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Thank you for the information, Chris.

Answer (score 0):

The park switches are all a bit dodgy and prone to wear of the contacts. I have used a heavy double-throw relay.

Instead of the motor, switch the relay coil with the wiper on/off switch low speed (or only speed), with the other side of the relay to GND. Connect the park switch contacts 2 and 4 over the contact of the wiper on/off switch. Connect the positive feed (12 V or 24 V) to the make contact and GND to the break contact of the relay. Then connect the wiper low speed (or only speed) wire of the wiper motor to the central contact and the other side of the motor to GND.

The relay stays ON as long as the switch is in low speed (high speed has no effect on this). When the switch is put to OFF the relay will stay on as long as the park switch is on. In the park position the relay will drop and the wiper motor is connected to GND on both sides thus forcing a break.

A relay is cheap and has a long life expectancy and the park switch is not going to burn its contacts. Don't forget a diode like a 1N4007 from GND to positive to prevent surge peaks when switching off (the little bar on the diode point to the positive). Some relays have a built-in diode which is nice.